# how to design a webpage for all resolution monitors

Tags: asp.net

I have created one web application in asp.net. In my computer'resolution it works fine with out any stretch. But some other monitor resolutions my web application streched. How to solve that screen resolution problem?

Comment: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-fluid-layouts-html5-and-css3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution problem also occurs with different browsers, There is one way to adjust your screen width to 1024 x 768 and apply center align to your content. And the other way is that you can adjust with percentage to 100% so it would be shrunken and expand as per resolution. If you will take 1024 x 768 resolution as the lowest resolution for your site hence it will not consider 800x600 resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ASP.NET unless you're a time-traveller from the year 2003, when Visual Studio had "grid mode" for HTML pages, including ASP.NET.

...we don't talk about those times anymore :)

It's a HTML+CSS thing. The key things to keep in mind for a flexible layout are:

- Keep blocks of text sized with the `em` unit so they're constant - long runs of text are very hard to read, as are very narrow columns. I suggest between `20em` and `30em` for text.
- Depending on your aesthetic, layout elements (banners, headers, etc) could be sized as a percentage of the viewport width or as a fixed width, both are valid. You can also use `max-width` and `min-width` to specify bounds on an element's box's size, thus allowing a single site design to scale from smartphone-sized screens to super-huge 2560x1400 displays.
- If you have very limited design experience: do not be adventurous. This is how disasters are made, when people try to be too ambitious (think: sites where *all* the content is loaded with AJAX, or late-1990s Geocities sites with animated GIFs and background MIDI tracks playing).

...and that's all that really needs to be said from a design-theoretic point of view. If you need help with implementing the design in CSS then I suggest checking out the links the other people posted in their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using Twitter's Bootstrap tool (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). It is a nice set of CSS rules that allow easy creation of fluid layouts.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer...

Answer (score 0):

USE **CSS3 MEDIA QUERIES** with the help of **RESPOND.JS** for IE

Refer

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/10/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/